# Can one #define a literal string containing non-ANSI characters for a resource file?

Tags: c++, c

I have a .h file that gets generated by my build script and #included by a resource file, but it won't build because of the (tm) symbol:

```
#define PRODUCT_NAME Acme Widget™ 1.2.3
```

The error I get back is `CommonAssemblyInfo.h(7): error RC2018: unknown character '0xe2'`.

Clearly I can just work around it by using (TM), but I'd prefer to use the "correct" symbol. Can it be done in this manner?

---

**UPDATE**

I should have been more complete in describing the problem and for that I apologize. It turns out that I omitted an important detail: the header file in question is being included by a resource file, and therefore the error is coming from the resource compiler. I'm updating the title of this post to reflect the fact.

Comment: Try a pair of quotation marks.

Comment: For a start: why don't you add `"` around the text? It should clearly be a string literal. Then you should check your encoding. Wrt the specific problem: Provide a [mcve] with **all** required information. And why did you add the UTF-8 tag? are you sure this is UTF-8? Which input character set does the compiler use? Which output character set?

Comment: In principle, you should be able to use \u2122 to represent ™ (which is U+2122, or hex bytes E2 84 A2 in UTF-8).

Comment: @Olaf, sorry for omitting details. And you're right, it was hasty to tag this as a UTF-8 problem when it's more generically a character set problem. I'll remove the UTF-8 tag and try to improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Visual C++ Resource Compiler does not understand UTF-8, but only knows about ANSI and Unicode:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/214917/

> The RC compiler supports UTF-16. As for UTF-8 it is currently not supported by the RC Compiler. An easy workaround for this inconvenient is to convert the rc file to UTF-16 using Visual Studio Save As functionality.

The bug was closed as "by design" on 2006-10-24 -- over ten years ago. Pity UTF-8 hasn't caught on... /s

Sure enough, when I saved the file as Unicode, all was well.

Answer (score 1):

C11 has syntax for UTF-8-encoded string literals.  For your particular string, it would look like this (supposing that the source, or at least this part of it, is encoded in UTF-8):

```
#define PRODUCT_NAME u8"Acme Widget™ 1.2.3"
```

C does not provide for characters outside its basic character set to appear in source files outside of wide / Unicode string literals, though some implementations may accept them as an extension.

An alternative would be to embed the bytes of the encoding into an ordinary string literal, or indeed into raw macro replacement text:

```
#define PRODUCT_NAME Acme Widget\xE2\x84\xA2 1.2.3
```

It's not much use to omit the string delimiters, however, because the hex escape syntax is only meaningful in the context of string and integer character literals.

Most portable, however, would be to use a Unicode escape as @chux suggests in comments.  In that case, however, I see no disadvantage to given the whole string as a utf-8 string literal:

```
#define PRODUCT_NAME u8"Acme Widget\u2122 1.2.3"
```

Comment: Perhaps `"Acme Widget" u8"\u2122" " 1.2.3"` to avoid using the `™`.

Comment: Good suggestion @chux, though I don't see any advantage in this case to segregating the UTF-8 part and relying on string concatenation.

Comment: Agree about this case.  Had OP wanted `"...Widget™1..."` (no space), segregating would be needed as `"Widget\u21221"` would not be correct. By segregating, as general style, avoids this error.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac (running macOS Sierra 10.12.3 with GCC 6.3.0), in a terminal with locale set by `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, the following variations all compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRODUCT_STRING     "Acme Widget™ 1.2.3"
#define PRODUCT_UTF8       "Acme Widget\u2122 1.2.3"

#define PRODUCT_NAME        Acme Widget™ 1.2.3
#define STRINGIFY(x)        # x
#define CVT_TO_STRING(x)    STRINGIFY(x)

int main(void)
{
    puts(CVT_TO_STRING(PRODUCT_NAME));
    puts(PRODUCT_STRING);
    puts(PRODUCT_UTF8);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition tm17.c -o tm17
$
```

The output, you won't be surprised to learn, is:

```
Acme Widget™ 1.2.3
Acme Widget™ 1.2.3
Acme Widget™ 1.2.3
```

In theory, the `\u2122` is the best (most portable) notation to use.

I also tested `#define PRODUCT_NAME Acme Widget\u2122 1.2.3`; that compiled and produced the same output.

Unicode escapes were added to C99; you might need to specify `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` (or use C11 instead) to get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Replace ™ for unicode \u2122

Use quotes

```cpp
#define PRODUCT_NAME "Acme Widget\u2122 1.2.3"
```